# Middle element as wide as the box allows

Tags: html, css, width, responsive

Hey guys I need you help.

I'm currently working on a small project so that I can learn "Atomic Design".

I've encountered a problem now.

I have a table.

```
<table class="search-table">
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2">
                            <form class="search">
                                <button class="icon-button enabled"><p class="default"><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></p></button>
                                <input type="text" class="search enabled" placeholder="Suchen...">
                                <input type="submit" class="button enabled default" value="Suchen">
                            </form>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Tabellenkopf (1)</th>
                        <th>Tabellenkopf (2)</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Zeile (1)</td>
                        <td>Zeile (1)</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
```

The width of the table is set to 100% and I want the `input type="text"` to be as wide as the remaining space allows. The `button` and the `input type="submit"` have fixed width.

I've already set

```
input[type="text"] {
    width: auto;
    min-width: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
```

and tried to `float:right` the `input type="submit"` but the `input type="text"` always pushed the button to the next "row".

Nothing seems to work.

Comment: Just add this line <input id="txt" type="text" onkeypress="this.style.width = ((this.value.length + 1) * 8) + 'px';">

Comment: Thanks but that's not really what I've been looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flex box is your friend in this situation, add `display:flex;` to form and `flex-grow:1` to input text

and you will have the following result:

```css
.search-table {
  width: 100%;
}

.search-table form{
  display:flex;
  width:100%;
}

.search-table form input[type="text"]{
    flex-grow:1;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<table class="search-table" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">
      <form class="search">
        <button class="icon-button enabled">
           <i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </button>
        <input type="text" class="search enabled" placeholder="Suchen...">
        <input type="submit" class="button enabled default" value="Suchen">
      </form>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Tabellenkopf (1)</th>
    <th>Tabellenkopf (2)</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Zeile (1)</td>
    <td>Zeile (1)</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks. Totally forget to use flexbox on that xD I'm learning so much new at my internship that I sometimes forget to use what I've already learned :D

Comment: The more you use something, the more more you remember it.. glad it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use calc

```
 .search-table form input[type="text"]{
        width:calc(100% - 100px);
    }
```

100px is width of button and the input type="submit"